# Oracle Advanced Queue, Java and Maven : unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, oracle-aq

Not getting in any project and even jdbc dependency:

First time tried project using Oracle Advanced Queue in Maven and got following error

```
Failed to collect dependencies at com.oracle:aqapi:jar:11.2.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.oracle:aqapi:jar:11.2.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.oracle:aqapi:pom:11.2.0.0 from/to integrator-releases (https://artifactory.fintegrator.cosng.net/libs-release): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>aqapi</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there anything i am missing with?

Repositories:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>integrator-libs-release-local</id>
      <name>Integrator Libraries Release Local</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.fintegrator.cosng.net/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>integrator-libs-snapshot-local</id>
      <name>Integrator Libraries Snapshot Local</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.fintegrator.cosng.net/libs-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

[image]

Comment: How does the minimal `pom.xml` look like that produces this error? What Maven command did you try?

Comment: @JanezKuhar: Tried normal Clean Install. It check from some repository which is configured and start giving this but i have .jar in my m2 in same package but it is not picking up from there

Comment: does the artifacory has the jar  com.oracle:aqapi:pom:11.2.0.0 ?

Comment: @OğuzhanAygün: No Artifcatory does not have the same thats why put it on local. It searched in artifactory and then mvn repo but also shall check local?

Comment: @fatherazrael Maven searches the artifacts local first and then queries the remote repository. If there is no match then throws an error. From the accepted answer I understand your groupId and version was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using some dated dependencies.

Try these instead:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
  <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.messaging</groupId>
  <artifactId>aqapi</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: aqapi is there any newer version most of oracle jar has 19.13.0.0.1 version but I cant see aqapi newer one?

Comment: @Bilgehan In which jar have you seen version 19.13.0.0.1 of aqapi?

Comment: 19.3.0.0 in maven I found is there newer version of aqapi